# How to deal with the pre schooler who hates wearing uniform daily?

Tags: pre-schooler, clothes

The child is 3.6 years old, and it is not her fault that she dislikes wearing school uniform daily.
It doesn't have anything to do with comfort. It is all about wearing the same boring stuff daily.

She is currently enrolled in pre-nursery which lasts for 3 hours. The school has enforced the uniform.

Daily morning she cries and begs us not make her wear the uniform. She also stays in the daycare there and they do change her clothes after the school is over.
I do tell her daily that it is the matter of 3 hours, and then she will be wearing something else, but this doesn't help.

How to deal with the pre schooler who hates wearing uniform daily, *without candies*?

Country: India

Comment: Does she enjoy pre-school?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Many times while returning she says she'll miss her friends. In all the videos they send to us, I see her playing games happily and participating happily in everything. Many times she says (when asked) that she does like the pre-school. But..... many times she tells me to come early to fetch her because she doesn't like to stay there. Many times she cries when we hand her over to the pre-school. @anongoodnurse

Comment: Hey, i'm 27 and i still hate this idea of wearing the same stuff everyday, but we have to sometimes, she must understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to follow the rules. You can commiserate without breaking the rules. However, what about great underwear? Go out and buy the best superhero, or frilliest underwear possible. Tell your kid that no one else is wearing THAT under their uniform. Let your child select which underwear to put on that day. Tell her it is her special thing and no one can say it is not okay -- especially if she doesn't tell everyone.

Maybe the uniform allows for different colours of shirts or hair bows or socks or sweaters. Let those things be a different as possible.

It's true that uniforms make everyone the same, which is very nice if the community has widely differing economic lifestyles. Point out that the uniform helps people (especially staff) treat everyone fairly.

Comment: Based on your first paragraph, you'll also have to teach the child not to go comparing underwear with the other children... :-)

Comment: "especially if she doesn't tell everyone." I could have added that she should not, but did not think it was necessary.